# Single table inheritance - Omniauth with multiple providers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations, single-table-inheritance

I am using Omniauth with multiple identities to login (i.e., Facbook, LinkedIn etc.). Right now, I have a single model called Service, with `provider` (with values `facebook`, `linkedin` etc.), `oauth_token` and some other fields.

Now, I added many methods to Service model, which only applied to a particular provider. For example, `friend_count`, which only applies if provider is `facebook`.

I think my code starts to smell and needs refactoring. I don't think I will add a lot of columns that are provider-specific, so polymorphism would not be necessary.

My question is: which design pattern I should take: single-table inheritance, or something simpler?